# How to get starting column number of the pattern matched in vim?

Tags: unix, vim

Suppose a line like this in vim:

```
ABC .DEF
```

I want to match `.` as a pattern to get its column which is 4.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details. What exactly do you mean with "to get its column"? When I search for a pattern and the cursor is at an occurrence, then I get the line number and column number displayed in the bottom line. Or is your question how to search for a literal `.`? (As `.` stands for "any single character", either escape it as `/\.` or use it in a set like `/[.]`. The `/` is the search command, not part of the pattern.)

Comment: @bodo to bne perfectly frank what is being asked is obvious. The answer from Armali taught me something. I don't know why you locked this.

Comment: @bodo Sorry I assumed you locked the question. If I made an incorrect assumption apologies

Comment: @Steve I didn't vote to close the question, but a few other users did because it needs details or clarity. This means that these users agree with my impression that the question is not clear enough. I first write a comment to ask for clarification and vote to close only if the OP does not improve the question. (So now I would vote to close.) Without knowing the OP's use case and what "to **get** its column" means, it is not clear if the significantly longer command from the answer provides some benefit over typing `/\.` and reading the column number that is displayed in the status line.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> ABC .DEF
> ```
>
> I want to match `.` as a pattern to get its column which is 4.

No, columns are numbered from 1, so `.`'s column is 5.

You search with [`search`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#search%28%29) and get the column with [`col`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#col%28%29):

```
:echo search('\.') ? col(".") : "not found"
```